# Why isnt' this multiple field key working in Mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I've added this to my model:

```
key :name, :random_number
```

And I am using this callback:

```
before_create :create_random_number
```

But random_number is not getting appended to the _id using a method like this:

```
def create_random_number
   rand(99999999999999999999)
end
```

This is the result that I get:

```
>> Product.create(name: "foo")
   => <Product _id: foo,
```

Comment: I have had the same issue in the past. Let me look to see if I can find the documentation that I used to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that you need to use after_initialize. This works for me:

```
key :slug
after_initialize :create_slug

def create_slug
  name = self.name.gsub(' ', '-')
  self.slug = "#{name}-#{rand(36**20).to_s(36)}"
end
```